# Creating a shortcode

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to create a gird which is 1:1 which I have done but there must be a tidier way. I will be editing this text and image everyday so need it to be tidy and easy to determine what is what... here is what I have done so far, which is far from ideal...

I'd like to do it via short-code but I'm not sure how to approach it. Perhaps someone here can help me out?

```
 // Add Shortcode
function AdvisoryFunc( $atts ) {

    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'text' => 'text',
            'image' => 'IMG',
        ),
        $atts,
        'AdvisoryTag'
    );

}
add_shortcode( 'AdvisoryTag', 'AdvisoryFunc' );
```

Comment: The documentation is pretty helpful and thorough: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: @disinfor Sure, if you've done it before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler bet would be to use a simpler grid by sticking some CSS like so in your Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS section:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .grid { width: 100%; display: table; table-layout: fixed; }
    .grid > * { display: table-cell; }
}
```

This would let you do the following on your page

```
<div class="grid">
    <div>Text</div>
    <img src="/path/to/img" />
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you may consider using a Custom Post Type, either with the [CPT API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) or a plugin like the widely used [CTP UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin. From there you could make a [Post Type Template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates) or a [Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) that pulls in the Content and Featured Image from the most recent post. Honestly, this is probably what I would do in your shoes, as it would allow an easier avenue for updating/managing the Statuses as well as provided a record of previous statuses, at the cost of having a bit more "set up" time.

---

Lastly, if you do just want to use a shortcode, you can use something like the following:

```
add_shortcode( 'advisory_tag', function( $atts ){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'text'  => 'Placeholder Text',
        'image' => '/placeholder/image.jpg'
    ), $atts ) );

    ob_start(); ?>

    <div class="section group">
        <div class="col span_1_of_2"><?= $text; ?></div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_2">
            <a href="<?= $image; ?>" target="_blank" title="Click to Enlarge" rel="noopener" style="outline: none;">
                <img src="<?= $image; ?>" alt="Advisory Image for <?= date( 'l, F jS, Y' ); ?>" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php $ob = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $ob;
});
```

Then all you have to do use put `[advisory_tag text="Some Text Here" image="link/to/image.jpg"]` in the post, and update that as you wish

Comment: That is perfect! I'm going to use the short-code for now but will definitely investigate the custom post type. You've been massively helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: My pleasure, glad you got it working! I did just notice I had a type in the images `alt` attribute (Adivsory instead of Advisory) - you may want to update that when you get around to it. Cheers!

Comment: All updated. I have also noticed that when I remove the code from within the Wordpress backend (that I had before your solution) the columns do not work. So it seems that the column code from within functions.php isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: Well there's this line in your HTML that loads the column styles `<style id="x-generated-css">a,h1 a:hover......` so make sure that's still there when you update it

Comment: Hm, i cannot seem to find that anywhere. Where are you seeing it?

Comment: If you look at the [page source](view-source:https://metcast.net/status/) it appears to be on line 83

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function AdvisoryFunc( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'image' => '',
    ), $atts );

    return '
        <div class="section-group">
            <div class="col-1">' . $content . '</div>'
            <div class="col-2"><img src="' . $a['image'] . '"></div>
        </div><!-- /section-group -->';
}

add_shortcode( 'AdvisoryTag', 'AdvisoryFunc' );
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
[AdvisoryTag image="http://www.examplesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/image.jpg"]Your html content goes here[/AdvisoryTag]
```

You will have to adjust the HTML within the `return` statement to match your HTML structure (classes and image attributes), but this should get you pretty close to getting it complete.